# Gerrit Installation On Windows 7 Tomcat and Mysql Error - MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=26' at line 1

Tags: mysql, tomcat7, gerrit

I have installed and configured **Gerrit** on windows using **Apache Tomcat** and **MySql**. I followed the instructions found [here](https://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-42271). However the configurations were sucessful the database was created and it was deployed to tomcat however when i run the application i am getting Code Review Error - 500 Internal Server Error.

I am not sure why this is happening or if this is normal once no projects have been created in **Gerrit**. Under is a screen shot of the error. The error logs on Apache Tomcat does not have any errors.

[image]

**Tomcat error log**

I am using MySql Administrator 1.2.17 and mysql-connector-java-5.1.27

```
[2013-12-12 11:21:00,341] ERROR com.google.gerrit.httpd.restapi.RestApiServlet : Error in GET /changes/?n=25&O=1
com.google.gwtorm.server.OrmException: fetch failure on changes
    at com.google.gwtorm.schema.sql.SqlDialect.convertError(SqlDialect.java:152)
    at com.google.gwtorm.jdbc.JdbcAccess.convertError(JdbcAccess.java:448)
    at com.google.gwtorm.jdbc.JdbcAccess.queryList(JdbcAccess.java:146)
    at com.google.gerrit.reviewdb.client.Change_Access_changes_GwtOrm$$13.allOpenNext(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.query.change.SqlRewriterImpl$11.scan(SqlRewriterImpl.java:291)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.query.change.SqlRewriterImpl$PaginatedSource.scan(SqlRewriterImpl.java:645)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.query.change.SqlRewriterImpl$ChangeSource.read(SqlRewriterImpl.java:608)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.query.change.AndSource.readImpl(AndSource.java:110)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.query.change.AndSource.read(AndSource.java:94)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.query.change.QueryProcessor.queryChanges(QueryProcessor.java:259)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.query.change.QueryChanges.query0(QueryChanges.java:158)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.query.change.QueryChanges.query(QueryChanges.java:146)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.query.change.QueryChanges.apply(QueryChanges.java:113)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.query.change.QueryChanges.apply(QueryChanges.java:42)
    at com.google.gerrit.httpd.restapi.RestApiServlet.service(RestApiServlet.java:306)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:278)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:268)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:180)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:85)
    at com.google.gwtexpui.server.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.gerrit.httpd.RunAsFilter.doFilter(RunAsFilter.java:113)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.gerrit.httpd.AllRequestFilter$FilterProxy$1.doFilter(AllRequestFilter.java:64)
    at com.google.gerrit.httpd.AllRequestFilter$FilterProxy.doFilter(AllRequestFilter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.gerrit.httpd.RequestContextFilter.doFilter(RequestContextFilter.java:75)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:120)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:132)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:129)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$Context.call(GuiceFilter.java:206)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:129)
    at com.google.gerrit.httpd.WebAppInitializer.doFilter(WebAppInitializer.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1760)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=26' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1031)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3376)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3308)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1837)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1961)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2537)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeSimpleNonQuery(StatementImpl.java:1463)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1875)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at com.google.gwtorm.jdbc.JdbcAccess.queryList(JdbcAccess.java:134)
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: What about Gerrit's logs in its `logs` directory?

Comment: The only file i am seeing in the logs directory is sshd_log and it is empty. I did not enable ssh when configuring Gerrit could this be the cause? Also i do not think i enabled logging since i did not see a classes directory in the gerrit WEB-INF directory

Comment: @MagnusBäck I am not seeing a classes directory in the WEB-INF all it has is extra, lib, pgm-lib,plugins and web.xml

Comment: I would try with a different database (PostgreSQL?) it could save you a lot of time.

Comment: @PiotrSzwed i actually got it working with mysql

Answer (score -1):

It could happen that if you installed gerrit on existing db (or upgrade existing gerrit to new version) you have to refresh the indexes in the database:

```
java -jar gerrit.war reindex -d /your/gerrit_app_directory
```

Comment: Please argue why? I had same exception and that solve the issue. It seems that gerrit is trying to fetch change sets and there is some inconsistent in the db.